# database design & relations for tourism web app

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm currently developing a web app on a travel & tourism website. What I'm willing to do is to allow the user to register himself to be able to book a tour for himself and/or family members. The 'family members' need not to register themselves. And the user should be able to cancel any member/himself from the booking. The tables I've designed so far are:

**`users`**
`id`,
`name`,
`password`,
`email`,
`phone`,
`level` (to distinguish between user & admin),
`dob` (date of birth),
`status` (active or blocked)

**`tours`**
`id`,
`title`,
`short_desc`,
`start_date`,
`end_date`,
`max_passenger_capacity`,
`fees`,
`published` (boolean),
`long_desc`

**`passengers`** (for additional passengers who are not registered)
`id` (PK),
`user_id` (FK from `users`),
`name`,
`age`,
`sex`,
`status`

**`wallets`** (where users can deposit money and pay from)
`id` (PK),
`user_id` (FK from users),
`date_time`,
`narration`,
`ref_no`,
`withdraw` (float),
`deposit` (float)

Now I intend to create an `invoice` table (`id`, `date`, `user_id` etc.), `invoice_items` table (`id`, `invoice_id`, etc. with reference to who is booking which tour for whom), `passengers_booked` table (`id`, `tour_id`, `passenger_id` etc. to keep track of which passenger is opting which tour).

The user should be able to cancel all the members from a tour or any member from the tour. In the later case an invoice should be raised quoting any refund and the other members should stay opted for the tour.

And how should manage the condition when the user is opting a tour for himself? And how to manage such invoice_items so that he can cancel himself?

I'm totally lost. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few thoughts on `users` and `invoices` structures to hopefully get you back on track. You'll probably need to clarify your question regarding other aspects (e.g. refunds).

---

To cope with `users` optionally being `passengers`, you could create a common `people` table, the `people_id` being a FK in both `passengers` and `users`. Hopefully, this should help keep your subsequent queries simpler and ease the processes whereby `users` become `passengers`, and possibly where `passengers` become registered `users` too. For example:

**`people`**: `id` (PK), `name`, `dob`, `sex`

**`users`**: `id` (PK), `people_id`, `password`, `email`, `phone`, `level`, `status`

**`passengers`**: `id` (PK), `people_id` (FK from people), `status` (as a passenger)

Notes:

- Would `people.name` be better as multiple fields (`forename` and `surname`)?
- You might consider `email` and `phone` better as fields on `people` rather than `users` (balancing redundancy against potential marketing)?
- Use `dob` consistently, rather than `age` (as this will require maintaining).
- You might think about how you keep entries on the `people` table unique to help prevent  duplicates being added for the same person.

---

With respect to Invoices and Refunds section, I'm not entirely sure what is required from the fragment you posted. Consider the following:

**`invoice`**: `id` (PK), `invoice_date`, `user_id`, `tour_id`, `invoice_amount`

**`passengers_booked`**: `id` (PK), `tour_id`, `passenger_id`

**`wallets`**: `id` (PK), `user_id` (FK from users), `transaction_date_time`, `narration`, `invoice_no NULL` (FK to invoice), `ref_no`, `transaction_amount` (float)

Notes:

- I'm not sure what your intention was for `invoice_detail`, as you know who's booking for whom by joining `invoice` and `passengers_booked` on `tour_id`.
- Refunds would be handled by posting any refund amount to the relevant `wallet` record.
- I've combined `withdrawal` and `deposit` into a single `transaction_amount` field to remove redundancy and ease the processing when, for example, calculating balances. The types can be distinguished using +ve and -ve values. [Although you may have accounting standards that mandate separate fields.]
- I've added `invoice_no` to `wallet` to track payments and refunds relating to a particular trip (but may be `NULL` for deposits/withdrawals). Similarly, `ref_no` may then be used when deposits/withdrawals into the wallet are received. [n.b. You *might* consider combining `invoice_no` and `ref_no`.]

**Example**

> User U is booking for a tour T for himself and his family members A,
>   B, C & D. And he also made the payment. Lets assume cost for tour T is
>   $1000/passenger. So he made a payment of $5000.

The `users` table has a record for user U.
The `tours` table has a record for tour T.
The `people` table has 5 records for U, A, B, C, D.
The `passengers` table has 5 records.
The `passengers_booked` table has 5 records for tour T.
The `invoice` table has a record dated e.g. '1 Jan' for $5000 for tour T.
The `wallet` has a deposit record for $5000.
The `wallet` also has a payment of -$5000 against our invoice.

> Now he wishes to cancel the booking of B. And for that he will be refunded (suppose)
>   $900 after cancellation charge.

The B record is removed from `passengers_booked` (but can be left on `passengers` for future use).
The `invoice` table is updated with revised date e.g. '8 Jan' and amount $4100.
The `wallet` table has a refund made to it against that invoice for $900.

Thus we use a single invoice which only holds the latest position.
You can check the latest invoice amount against the sum of wallet entries for that invoice, to see whether there is an amount outstanding or due for refund.

n.b. There are other ways to model this, e.g. use `invoice` as the summary as above but have multiple `invoice_detail` records to capture the detail on passenger changes. Depending on why you're doing this and how sophisticated it needs to be will determine which route is better for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your suggestions are really good. I'm willing to work with that approach. Wallets are virtual banks for the users. I want them to pay for tour booking from the wallet. And in case of refund the amount will be added back to wallet.

Comment: ok thanks -- From your comment, I've updated the invoice section with a structure that should work. Obviously, you'll need to be comfortable that you understand how it supports your requirements. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems that I will be able to progress a lot with your suggestion. Now, as far as the refund is concerned, take for example, let's say an user U is booking for a tour T for himself and his family members A, B, C & D. And he also made the payment. Lets assume cost for tour T is $1000/passenger. So he made a payment of $5000. Now he wishes to cancel the booking of B. And for that he will be refunded (suppose) $900 after cancellation charge. Can you please suggest how can I handle cancellation invoice and all that stuffs for this situation?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm progressing as per your suggestion. I'll let you know about it soon. Thanks again.